# C++: Get LPCWSTR from wstringstream?

Tags: c++, string, unicode

If I have a `wstringstream`, and I want to get its `.str()` data as a LPCWSTR, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do `wstringstream.str().c_str()` [as DeadMG writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991740/c-get-lpcwstr-from-wstringstream/2991760#2991760). However, the result of that call is only valid until the end of lifetime of the expression, this is part of.

Specifically, this

```
const LPCWSTR p = wss.str().c_str();
f(p); // kaboom!
```

***will not work***, because `wstringstream.str()` returns a temporary object and `.c_str()` returns a pointer into that object, and at the end of the assignment that temporary object will be destructed.

What you can do instead is either

```
f(wss.str().c_str()); // fine if f() doesn't try to keep the pointer
```

or

```
const std::wstring& wstr = wss.str(); // extends lifetime of temporary 
const LPCWSTR p = wstr.c_str();
f(p); // fine, too
```

because temporary objects bound to a `const` reference will have their lifetime extended for the reference's lifetime.

Comment: or, if assigned to a constant reference, the lifetime of the reference

Comment: @Greg: I was just in the process of writing this. `:)`

Comment: I think your second code is not fine, because C++ can destroy the temporary before `f` gets called. This really happened to me once! So you must never store the result of `c_str()` or `data()`.

Comment: @Philipp: It's not legal for the temporary to be destroyed until the end of the evaluation of the full expression so you must have been using a buggy compiler if this happened to you.

Comment: How about we create just a simple wstring object? does it get invalidated too? even we use copy constructor (or assignment at init) as `wstring s(wstr.str()); f(s.c_str());` Whats the difference? especially scope/lifetime extension stuff? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`wstringstream.str().c_str();`